# How do I push a controller on a presented controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to push a controller by clicking home button on the controller and this controller is already presented.

This is an IBAction of Agree button:

```
@IBAction func onTapDownloadButton(_ sender: Any) {
    routerSummary?.routeToOtpResendViewController()
}
```

This is the function which should be running when on tapped and should display MapViewController:

```
func routeToMapViewController() {
    let destVC = MapViewController.load(from: .map)
    self.viewControllerSummary?.navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
}
```

[image: Image of the presented controller]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information. Is it true that your routeToOtpResendViewController function presents the resend view controller modally?

Is it also true that the resend view controller is wrapped into a navigation controller, and what you present is actually the parent navigation controller of the resend view controller? (You must have presented a navigation controller in order to be able to push another view controller onto it. This is likely the reason your code isn't working.)

Comment: Note that it is a bit odd to first present a modal view controller, and then push a view controller onto that modal's navigation stack. Usually you present a modal, dismiss it, and do something else. Sometimes you'll present a second modal on top of the first, but the idea of a modal is a screen that temporarily interrupts the flow of screens and has to be dismissed before the user can continue.